# Getting logging.debug() to work on Google App Engine/Python

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine

I'm just getting started on building a Python app for Google App Engine.  In the localhost environment (on a Mac)

I'm trying to send debug info to the GoogleAppEngineLauncher Log Console via `logging.debug()`, but it isn't showing up.  However, anything sent through, say, `logging.info()` or `logging.error()` *does* show up.  I've tried a `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` before the `logging.debug()`, but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag is `--log_level debug`.

Concretely, start your dev server with this command line:

```
dev_appserver.py --log_level debug .
```

You can find this information by running `dev_appserver.py --help`. Here's the relevant quote from the command output:

> --log_level {debug,info,warning,critical,error}
>                           the log level below which logging messages generated
>                           by application code will not be displayed on the
>                           console (default: info)

Using an equal sign (i.e., `--log_level=debug`) will also work, because the python script `google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py` relies on the `argparse` module, and the latter handles both spaces and the equal sign the same way, as stated in the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax).

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/17350827/242848, it's `--log_level=debug` (with '=' sign).  Could you clarify/doublecheck, and possible point to some documentation and I will change the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Both `--log_level=debug` and `--log_level debug` work, because of the way the `argparse` python module is designed. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, this is now the accepted answer.  Could you change your first sentence to be less confusing.  E.g. 'accepted answer' -> 'previously accepted answer'

Comment: I deleted the previously-accepted answer since it's wrong, so mentioning it at all in this answer isn't necessary :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have removed all mentions of an accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

In case someone is using the Windows Google Application Launcher. The argument for debug can be set under Edit > Application Settings

In the Extra Command Line Flags, add --log_level=debug

Comment: I have tried to do this, under launch settings. (extra command line flags) i put this in and update. It does not seem to keep the extra command line flag there it is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative to setting the log_level flag:

```
logging.getLogger().handlers[0].setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac:

1) click Edit > Application Settings

2) then copy and paste the following line into the "Extra Flags:" field

--log_level=debug

3) click Update

your debug logs will now show up in the Log Console