# Why wouldn't GAE store my logging.debug?

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine, logging

It seems `logging.debug()` doesn't appear in GAE logs, but `logging.error()` does.

Does anyone have an idea how can I make `logging.debug()` appear in the GAE logs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting logging.debug() to work on Google App Engine/Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982959/getting-logging-debug-to-work-on-google-app-engine-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logging in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) can be set to a different level, so that only a specified level of information appears in the log file. Try to change the logging level:

```
logging.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Incorrect - setting the logging level on App Engine in production does nothing, and setting it yourself in the SDK is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that on the SDK-Server debug logging really disappears. In production I get full debug logs. This may be because of the way I call `webapp.WSGIApplication`:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
     ('/', Homepage)],
    debug=True)
```

Do you also use `debug=True`. (Actually I always wondered what it exactly was meant to do)